# moving netbeans project to Windows 10 home

Tags: java, netbeans, directory, version

What are all netbeans project directories, where it can store various metadata?
I'd like to move my project to other computer (with new Netbeans version)
There are some directories where Netbeans stores data for the project (not just src directory), like .netbeans..cashe 
It sometimes stores additional libraries and other data somewhere else.
So, where to look for all that project data?
It is only one part of the question. The other part is : does Windows 10 home
have some problems with developing application on it? Because when I installed Netbeans 8.2 on it and tried to open (moved - maybe incorrectly) project , it made very strange things, when tried create new project, it made
nothing at all. I am totally new to Windows 10 home (had Windows XP)
Thank you and sorry for my English, if it sounds foreign

Comment: You're approaching it from the wrong angle. You should not migrate metadata between workspaces, just the source code. Your build tool (Maven? Gradle?) should take care of downloading and wiring in the libraries. IDE should take care of creating its own metadata it needs to operate.

Comment: just try to copy only your code or project

Answer (score 0):

You should not approach this way at all.

**In old machine**,

export your project as a zip file. refer [here](https://thscompsci.com/student-resources/turning-projects/)

**In new machine**

1. Install NetBeans
2. Create a workspace
3. Then import the project to your new work space